# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Connection request timed out - only when I deploy it to AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, amazon-ecs

As the question suggests.
I am trying to connect to the Oracle DB which is deployed on On-Premises servers with .net core API using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.

When I run the code locally, I **always** get results from my query. I am using AWS ECS Fargate for deployment of this code, and following are my observations:

1. Container health is ok, and other functionalities in the app are running fine
2. When i deploy the application, my api sometimes returns data and sometimes I get timeout error
3. When I get timeout error, my cloudwatch logs does not include any logic specific data
4. This exception is thrown when I try to run **connection.open()** method of the package
5. many time, my ecs goes to **Alarm of Memory and CPU utilization over 80%**

I have tried so many things from the internet and none of them worked for me, I am really in the need of help. Following are my configurations.

1. dotnet core 3.1 API
2. **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core Version="3.21.130"**
3. AWS ECS Fargate with **"mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1**: docker image
4. "OracleConnection": **"Data Source=<server>:1521/<service>;User Id=<user>;password=<pass>;Connection Timeout=120; Min Pool Size=50; Max Pool Size=150; Validate connection=true;"**
5. Also tried adding: **Load Balancing=true;Incr Pool Size=10; Statement Cache Purge=true; HA Events=true;** to the connection string, did not help
6. I am using AutoFac for DI: `builder.RegisterType<OracleDbContext().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();`
7. My request is not using TPA using TASK<>
8. When I connected to the DBA for this instance, he claimed that the request for connection is not even coming to the database

Exception I am getting:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Connection request timed out 
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)

    at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)

   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)

   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
```

Again, it works around 30 to 40% of the time, but most of the time I get this error. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.